# Displaying PHP variables in an email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to display a users first and last name at the end of an email message. The $firstname and $lastname are stored as session variables. This is the code:

```
//get user info from SESSION
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

//get mail function data
$case = $_POST['case'];
$to = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['to']));
$subject = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['subject']));
$from = "confirmation@domain.com";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$message = 

"
Thanks!

$firstname $lastname
$email

";
```

firstname, lastname and email are all blank in the message. Any ideas?

Mail function:

```
//send email
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f".$from)){
            //register into database
            $register_email = mysql_query 
            ("INSERT INTO `email` VALUES ('','$case','$userid','$to','$from','$subject','$message','$sent','$read','')");
            //formatting for error message
            $emailSent = "block";
            $emailFailed = "none";
        }
        else //if the email fails to send
        {
            $emailSent = "none";
            $emailFailed = "block";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Then your session variables are blank. You will need to investigate why (Did you do a `session_start()`?)

Comment: They are not blank. Thats what I thought initially.

Comment: @kjy112 I did an echo $message and the result is exactly what it should be. The session variables are echoed in the message.

Comment: so you aren't getting the $message to printout what it supposed to be in the mailed email?

Comment: Exactly. In the mailed email the message just has blank spaces where the variables ($firstname, $lastname and $email) are.

Comment: try use `\n` to format your $message variable

Comment: kjy112, that would not make a difference in the variables being printed within the message context, that would just muddle the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging the session data:

```
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

more than likely will be blank.

if the you try `var_dump($_SESSION)` and the data shows up, please apppend that to your post so we can verify that the data is being selected correctly.

Also you should double check your mail function to make sure that your sending the correct variable.

if non of the above work then please post your entire script for review.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION)` -- that should be helpful.

Comment: Can you show us where your sending the mail, such as `mail(...)`

Comment: also are you using windows or linux server

Comment: @kjy112, Why would that effect it?

Comment: Just added the mail function. Using linux server

Comment: on win server you have to use `\r\n`  else it won't mail the content.

Comment: @mike, what goes into the database ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this:

```
 $message = 

    "
    Thanks!

    $firstname $lastname
    $email

    ";
```

format newline with \n on linux or \r\n on windows server or you can use PHP `PHP_EOL`:

```
$message = "Thanks!\n$firstname $lastname\n$emal\n"; //liux 
$message = "Thanks!\r\n$firstname $lastname\r\n$emal\r\n"; //windows
// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

[PHP Mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Message to be sent.

Each line should be separated with a LF (\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters.

Comment: the variables would still be printed out on both, it would just be the formatting that differs .

Comment: also add if line are larger than 70 characs make sure to wordwrap it. man you are every where @RobertPitt thanks for catching the earlier mistake =)